# Magento 2 : Hide Product Images Using Database

Tags: magento2, product, image

I have migrated my products from Magento 1 to Magento 2. How to hide bulk product images? For example, I have product with 4 images found on backend, I want only one product will display on frontend. Aside from using backend is there another way to make it easier without manually hiding each product image on backend?

Comment: For each product image there is option to "Hide from Product Page" you can select this option to hide image from product page. based on this you can write down sql query to hide bulk product image in database

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query:

```
UPDATE catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value 
SET disabled = 1 WHERE position != 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should run this query:

```
update catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value 
set disabled = 1 where value_id not in 
(select value_id from catalog_product_entity_media_gallery where value in (select value from catalog_product_entity_varchar where attribute_id in (87, 88,89)))
```